# Django heroku internal server error after deploying

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, server

I have deployed my django app to heroku and I am getting `Internal Server Error` in the website.

settings.py :

`'ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/','https://stripetestdjango.herokuapp.com/', 'localhost']`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


MEDIA_URL = '/images/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)


MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_STORAGE =  'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage' 



if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    DEBUG = False
```

The heroku log shows the below:

[image]

I have .env file. How to push that to server as well as I am deploying using heroku. I guess the error is it is not able to find my .env file.

Please feel free to ask for more details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **never** push an `.env` file containing sensitive data (ie SECRET_KEY_STRIPE) but rather use [Heroku Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

You can fetch the env variable using Python `os`, while on your local development environment it is a good idea to keep the `.env` with the value you need for developing/testing.

```
def get_mysecret():
  return os.environ.get("MY_SECRET", "")
```

See screenshot (you can use create the Config Var with the command line if you prefer):
[image: Create Heroku ConfigVar]